# Segues from UITableView rows

Tags: uitableview, menu, swift3, segue

I use UITableView as a list of menu items and I want to open different views by tapping individual items (UITableView rows). I can create just one segue in IB which is not enough - I need more segues with starting point on UITableView row and leading to various views.
I did play a bit with code like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var destinationVC = UIViewController()
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        destinationVC = vcCountries()
    case 1:
        destinationVC = vcManagers()
    default:
        break
    }
    var seg = UIStoryboardSegue(identifier: "seg", source: self, destination: destinationVC)
    seg.perform()
}
```

but issue is that it fails with uncaught exception "'Could not perform segue with identifier 'seg'. A segue must either have a performHandler or it must override -perform.'"
What code I should writ into performHandler during seg initialization?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, it seems that I found solution. Segue start point should be hooked to view (not to UITableView row/cell) because in this case there could be more segues with the same start point.

Comment: Why don't you just `present` or `push` destinationViewController instead of creating a segue manually?

Comment: Thanks will try it as well but I solved my issue for now.